# Okta-Spring Boot keeps throwing 400 response using company provided okta registration information

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

Our company provided me with new okta registration information. Specifically, the following :

**okta.oauth2.issuer**=https://purpleid-test.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aaabbbbccc

**okta.oauth2.audience**=ABC12345

**okta.oauth2.client-id**=0oaSomeClientId

In my spring boot application, I have the following :

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ....
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ....
</project>
```

**Main class**

```
....
import java.security.Principal;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MessageConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    static class RootEndpointRestController {
        @GetMapping("/test")
        String test(Principal principal){
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,health,info,beans,refresh,bus-refresh
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true

server.port=8080

okta.oauth2.issuer=https://ourcompanyid-test.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aaabbbbccc
okta.oauth2.audience=ABC12345
okta.oauth2.client-id=0oaSomeClientId
```

**SecurityConfiguration class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "internet.proxy.ourcompany.com");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "5555");
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

**Problem :**
Whenever I try to access url like `localhost:8080/test` or `localhost:8080/actuator` in the browser (Chrome/Edge), it always returns **400 Bad Request**

In the browser URL, this is what shows up

```
https://ourcompanyid-test.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aaabbbbccc
v1/authorize?
response_type=code&
client_id=0oaSomeClientId&
scope=profile%20email%20openid&
state=I2VByus9KqEt_Zt0ivvG9j_IKtLBldoQrZg-a1SRsYM%3D&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/okta&
code_challenge_method=S256&
nonce=AISpoMaYWFKjp2ZdF_xncSd8LFw7FKTMK9D6G1xbP3o&
code_challenge=hi1EmraZOfOYsdn5rolIaRZO4-pbA8yHtMpIVxjcDP0
```

However, **when I use my personal Okta Developer account registration, it succeeds and redirects me to okta login** page when I try to access `localhost:8080/test` or `localhost:8080/actuator` in the browser (Chrome/Edge)

[image]

My personal Okta Developer account registration looks something like this :

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-123456.okta.com/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.client-id=0oaMyClientId
okta.oauth2.client-secret=MyClientSecret
```

I don't have any idea why it would work using my personal Okta registration info and why it would NOT work when I use the Okta registration provided by our company.

Basically, when I use my personal Okta, it redirects to Okta login page just fine. But when I use office provided Okta registration, it returns **400 Bad Request**

Is this something to do with my `SecurityConfiguration` class? Is my configuration class good?
Or, is this something that can be fixed by changing Okta configuration in Okta website?

NOTE: I was informed by the person who created the company okta registration that they created a Single-Page type of Okta registration.

I'd appreciate any comment, explanation or suggestion to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: After talking to our Okta support, we found that the root cause of this 400 bad request was an incorrect Client ID value that was given to me by mistake.
Another issue I faced was `400 Bad Request: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings` which was resolved by following the steps from this page : `https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/The-redirect-uri-parameter-must-be-an-absolute-URI?language=en_US`

Comment: Also, worthing mentioning is the Okta Application Type was SPA (Single Page Application) which does NOT require any client password.

Answer (score 0):

`@RestController`s are OAuth2 resource-servers. [Configure it as so](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). This can be as simple as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://ourcompanyid-test.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aaabbbbccc
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=groups

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/test
```

Follow link above for samples with more options (servlet VS reactive apps or JWT decoder VS access-token introspection, and last Spring default Authentictaion implementation VS custom ones), and also tips for testing (unit & integration) with mocked OAuth2 identities. Tutorials are providing with instructions for configuring resource-servers with just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` or spring-addons boot starters building on top of it (and much simplified Java configuration).